# installing ember-cli on ubuntu. ember new app fails silently

Tags: ubuntu, ember.js, ember-cli

I am planing to switch my ember development to ubuntu 12.04.  I am new to it. It seems I have installed node and ember-cli properly, but `ember new a` does not do anything and fails silently.

```
rigel@ rigel:/$ ember --version
0.2.8
rigel@rigel:/$ npm--version
1.4.23
rigel@ rigel:/$ node -v
v0.10.31
rigel@rigel:/$ember new a
rigel@ rigel:/$
```

The above mentioned information might be less than is needed to troubleshoot the problem, but I need some pointers to figure out what else I should be looking at.

Comment: node on ubuntu is stupid, ubuntu chose to install that dumb million year non nodejs package.  If you run it sudo'd does it partially work?  If so it's probably a permissions issue with your node/npm installation.

Comment: I think if it was permission issues it would likely have outputted some EACCES errors. I think @Oliver is correct in that you installed the wrong packaged (ember-tools). ember-cli is currently on version 0.0.40. Olivers answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you installed [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools) instead of [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli).

Make sure you get rid of ember-tools:

```
npm uninstall -g ember-tools
```

and make sure you have the latest version of ember-cli installed:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
```

Comment: yes i had install ember-tools which i loved. so the clash between ember-tools and ember-cli packages

Answer (score 0):

Your versions there (particularly for ember) are pretty old. I've found [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to work pretty well to install `node` and its modules in your homedir, rather than relying on what the OS packages can provide.

```
$ nvm current
v0.11.13
$ node -v
v0.11.13
$ npm -v
2.0.0-alpha-5
$ ember --version
version: 0.0.40
node: 0.11.13
npm: 1.5.0-alpha-4
```