# Where is ember? Or node for that matter?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to start an ember tutorial. I'd swear I've used node and npm before, but not super recently. I installed with `sudo npm install -g ember-cli` (doing it as a user got me errors indicating I needed sudo) and didn't see any errors. But `ember -v` returns nothing. No error, just a new command prompt. Same with `node --version`. Synaptic says I'm running node version 1.4.21+ds-2(vivid).

What am I missing here? Why can't ember run or return errors?

Note, I'm seeing the same behavior as this question:
[installing ember-cli on ubuntu. ember new app fails silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412290/installing-ember-cli-on-ubuntu-ember-new-app-fails-silently)

But with the added weirdness that even asking for the version fails.

Comment: did you install npm w/ sudo? If so ... can you brew install it instead (link to an OSX installer I use to setup new dev machines) https://github.com/toranb/osx-workstation/blob/master/installer#L26

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I installed `npm` with `apt-get`

Comment: Are you sure you are running nodejs and not node?  Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04.  I usually remove node completely and add nodejs.

Comment: Try running `npm install -g --verbose ember-cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Kingpin2k got it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130296/233467

At some point long ago I tried to install with `apt-get install node` which installed node, aka Amateur Packet Radio Node. Not what I wanted. But that put "node" right there in my path.

So I purged node, and symlinked `/usr/bin/node` to `/usr/bin/nodejs` and installed ember again. This time it seems to be there.